# Switch template in extension

Tags: extension, hooks, debugging, custom-templates

Extension loads and I added the following hook to switch demographics template:

```
function myext_civicrm_alterTemplateFile( $formName, &$form, $context, &$tplName) {
switch($tplName) {
    case "CRM/Contact/Form/Edit/Demographics.tpl":
      $mytpl='../templates/CRMContactFormEditDemographics.tpl';
        $template = CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
        if ($template->template_exists($mytpl)){
          $tplName=$mytpl;
        }
    break;
  }    


}
```

I think this worked before. What did I wrong? I put a breakpoint with my debugger or let it run to cursor position, but it never even gets there, so I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint (or a debug statement) above the switch statement, to make sure that the hook is being called?  It sounds like it might not be.

Comment: Well that's what I did. The hook was never called when creating / editing a contact. I discovered that hook_civicrm_alterContent does get called and I will use that instead, but that doesn't explain why alterTemplateFile was not called.

Answer (score 1):

I use alter template file in 4.7.2. It has been working great for me.

I needed to switch out the contact editor form based on contact subtype. One important thing I found if doing this programically was the clear the template cache.

```
function customcomponent_civicrm_alterTemplateFile($formName, &$form, $context, &$tplName) {

    // swith contact template based on contact type
    switch ($formName) {
        case 'CRM_Contact_Form_Contact':

            $clear = true;

            if ($form->_contactType!='Individual'||empty($form->_contactSubType)) break;

            // there are some weird non printable chars on contact sub type
            $contactSubType = preg_replace('/\W/i','',$form->_contactSubType);

            // switch out the form based on contact type
            $newTpl = 'CRM/Contact_'.$form->_contactSubType.'/Form/Contact.tpl';
            $newDir = __DIR__ .'/templatesconditional/ContactSubType_'.$contactSubType;

            break;
    }

    // clear out old templates -- found CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_UpdateConfigBackend::postProcess -> CRM_Core_Config::cleanup
    if (!empty($clear)) {
        $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();
        CRM_Utils_File::cleanDir($config->templateCompileDir, false);
        CRM_Utils_File::createDir($config->templateCompileDir);
    }

    // switch out the templates
    $template = CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
    if (!empty($newTpl)&&$template->template_exists($newTpl)) $tplName = $newTpl;
    if (!empty($newDir)&&is_dir($newDir)) $template->addTemplateDir($newDir);
}
```